# Multiple event binding shortcut

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, dom-events

What I am currently doing when binding same element to multiple actions in knockout is:

```
data-bind="event: { click: doAction,
                    touchend : doAction}"
```

**My question is :**
Is there some kind of shortcut notation that could be used when binding to actions?

I would expect something like :

```
data-bind="event: {click, touchend : doAction}"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not a built-in shortcut to do this, but it is pretty easy to use a custom binding to make your `data-bind` cleaner.

There are several approaches that you could take.  One solution specific to click and touchend would be:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.clickAndTouch = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data) {
         var action = valueAccessor(),
             newValueAccessor = function() {
                 return {
                     click: action,
                     touchend: action
                 }                     
             };

         ko.bindingHandlers.event.init.call(this, element, newValueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data);      
    }        
};
```

Then, you would bind against it like:

`data-bind="clickAndTouch: doAction"`

Comment: thx for the reply Ryan. this approach is nice and I will probably use it for my problem. But it seems to me the bindingHandlers would get huge in case of different combination of events (eg. : swipe+doubleclick, doubletap+doubleclick and so on)

Comment: Probably will use the normal long approach tho'. Chrome is not willing to deal with this type of binding :) Error in event handler for 'undefined': INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1 undefined event_bindings:207
chrome.Event.dispatch event_bindings:207
chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnMessage miscellaneous_bindings:250

Comment: @NazarGargol just curious if you can reproduce your error in jsFiddle.  Should not be any different than doing the long form: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/aLtds/

Comment: Also, it wouldn't be hard to write a binding that takes in an array of events and an action, but not sure that the syntax would be a whole lot better.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3S8eX/ - when double click is performed you get an exception (Chrome18/Chrome20).

Comment: I can't repro in Chrome 18 in the jsFiddle that you posted.  Not sure on this one.

Comment: nevermind, could be one of my numerous extensions colliding. thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

Since at least Knockout 2.1.0 (and it still works with 3.4.2) it is possible to use:

```
data-bind="event: {'click touchend': doAction}"
```